# How to use Servlet for HttpServer

Tags: servlets, httpserver

can i use servlet for a self implemented HttpServer(com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer) in eclipse(The HttpServer should start with the port no. and servlet should handle the client request.) ?
if yes sample code would be highly useful.

Comment: we will love to add to your efforts,show up some of your work

Comment: Basically yes - if you are building a servlet container - you'll need to initialize and fill the request and response objects before passing them to the servlet. What do you need that for? can you give more hints about your use case?

Comment: @A4L I m not able to "connect" my servlet with the HttpServer.I can handle the "GET" and "POST" inside my HttpServer itself(by implementing HttpHandler).But I need to initialize the servlet once the client sends the request to the server so that servlet handles the doGet and doPost instead of HttpHandler.

Comment: There is much more to a Java Servlet [web container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container) than an HTTP web server. You would study and implement the 246 page specification for Java Servlet 4 defined on [JSR 369](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=369). But what a colossal waste of time and effort, given the existence of Apache Tomcat, Eclipse Jetty, and many more. Why would you bother to roll-your-own?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49152824/642706 duplicates this Question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ServletContextListener isn't invoked when using com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53847095/servletcontextlistener-isnt-invoked-when-using-com-sun-net-httpserver-httpserve)